# MS-RDS sporadically slow redirect

Tags: windows-server-2016, rds

I've setup a 2016 RDS farm with **1 RD Connection Broker** (RDCB), **40 RD Session Hosts** (RDH), no Web Access and no Gateway. There are about 4000 connections (mostly reconnects) per hour. The connections are following this way: Client -> RDH -> RDCB -> RDH. Since I've got just one RDCB, this is no HA installation and the session database is local, not shared.

80% of the redirects are taking 0-1sec as they should, 10% are taking 2-10sec and 10% are taking more than 10 seconds. The time delta is always between the event ids 800 (redirection request received, TerminalServices-SessionBroker\Operational) and 801 (redirection request processed). I've not been able to find out what's taking the RDCB so long to redirect some sessions.

I've checked:

- hardware resources
- debug & analytic eventlogs

Has anyone experience with this phenomenon? Or else has anyone an idea how to further analyze it so that I'm able to find the real culprit?

Please feel free to ask for more information, I'll be more than happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Which os are you running this server on. If your running Windows home/pro then contact the server owners for network problems. If you are running server then it makes sense due to the fact that server is meant for shell like usage not graphical usage

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly. MS-RDS is of course running on (as I thought also clearly stated in the question) Windows Server 2016. The RDS role is exactly for remote **desktop** and as such graphical usage.

Answer (score -1):

Then as I said previously, contact the owner of the server for checking if that server has a proper physical connection to ethernet. It could just be a loose cable not allowing all the data to come through. Trust me it happened once